# SSIS passing a variable to execute sql task (create table parameter)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis, bids

I have a package that contains two execute sql tasks followed by numerous DFTs. The first has the statement:

```
select CAST(floor(rand()*1000)+1 AS INT) AS SeqVar
```

And has the ResultSet Single row - this works perfect. It gives me a random number between 1 and 1000 and passes that value on to a variable I have called SeqVar. (I have also verified that this works)

The problem I am having is in my second execute SQL task where I try and use the SeqVar variable outputted from the first Execute SQL teask as a parameter in the following statement:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.[##temp1]') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [##temp1]

CREATE TABLE [##temp1] (
[RecID] int IDENTITY(?,1),
[Name] VARCHAR(30),
[ABA] VARCHAR(10),
[Account] VARCHAR(20),  
[Type] VARCHAR(1),
[Date] date,
[Amount] money   
);
```

Under parameter mapping I have the SeqVar variable name, Direction is Input, Data Type numeric, Parameter name is 0, and Parameter size is 1000.

The value I get has to go where I have the "?" in the create tempdb statement. I am trying to have my code start at a random number and increment by 1.

I know this would probably be easier with a Script task but that tool is broken on my maching (weird dts pipeline errors). Thanks in advance and this is all in SSIS 2008.

Comment: Parameters don't work that way. You'll need to cook this up in an expression in a string and run the string. Script task is also broken on my machine! It seems pretty unreliable.

Comment: Solution: Kept the random number stored in the variable and set RecID as IDENTITY(1,1) when creating the temp table. Then in a derived column I had @SeqVar + RecID.  So each row that came in, the RecID iterated and was added to the random number.  Thanks for all of your input, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using identity in this way seems like a strange solution just to start a sequence at some random value. Parameters formatted as ? definitely don't work in that context in SQL.

However, another way to manage this, if the method is a given, is to set the entire code of your SQL task using an expression where you sub in the value as a simple string concatenation and then run the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

Better do create table as like below then use RESEED property to set it to your Random Variable Value'

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.[##temp1]') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [##temp1]

    CREATE TABLE [##temp1] (
    [RecID] int IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Name] VARCHAR(30),
    [ABA] VARCHAR(10),
    [Account] VARCHAR(20),  
    [Type] VARCHAR(1),
    [Date] date,
    [Amount] money   
    );

    DECLARE @RANDOM_VALUE INT = 50
    DBCC CHECKIDENT('##TEMP1',RESEED,@RANDOM_VALUE)
```